# xslt merge XML based on default structure and data

Tags: templates, xslt, dynamic

I would like to merge two XML-parts.
I like to create an dynamic XSLT which we can use for different conversions.
For the dynamic part, i have the idea for creating a structure-template which contains the needed output.

INPUT/SOURCE

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <DATA>
      <Transport>
        <Cars>
          <line>
            <brand>Opel</brand>
            <type>Corsa</type>
          </line>
        </Cars>
        <CarPrices>
          <line>
            <price>12000</price>
            <country>Belgium</country>
            <OptionPrices>
              <line>
                <introductionKit>400</introductionKit>
              </line>
            </OptionPrices>
          </line>
          <line>
            <price>15000</price>
            <country>Holland</country>
          </line>
        </CarPrices>
        <colors>
          <line>
            <color>red</color>
          </line>
          <line>
            <color>blue</color>
          </line>
        </colors>
      </Transport>
      <Transport>
        <Cars>
          <line>
            <brand>Opel</brand>
            <type>Omga</type>
          </line>
        </Cars>
        <CarPrices>
          <line>
            <price>16000</price>
            <country>Germany</country>
          </line>
        </CarPrices>
        <Engine>
          <line>
            <fuel>diesel</fuel>
            <type>1.6</type>
          </line>
        </Engine>
      </Transport>
    </DATA>
```

Output template
custom-made
The elements which contains the data will be visible under the parent.

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <Cars>
      <line>
        <CarPrices>
          <line>
            <OptionPrices/>
          </line>
        </CarPrices>
        <colors>
        </colors>
        <Engine>    
        </Engine>
        <Measurements>
        </Measurements>
      </line>
    </Cars>
```

Desired output

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Cars>
  <line>
    <brand>Opel</brand>
    <type>Corsa</type>
    <CarPrices>
      <line>
        <price>12000</price>
        <country>Belgium</country>
        <OptionPrices>
          <line>
            <introductionKit>400</introductionKit>
          </line>
        </OptionPrices>
      </line>
      <line>
        <price>15000</price>
        <country>Holland</country>
        <OptionPrices/>
      </line>
    </CarPrices>
    <colors>
      <line>
        <color>red</color>
      </line>
      <line>
        <color>blue</color>
      </line>
    </colors>
    <Engine>
      <line/>
    </Engine>
    <Measurements>
  </Measurements>
  </line>
  <line>
    <brand>Opel</brand>
    <type>Omga</type>
    <CarPrices>
      <line>
        <price>16000</price>
        <country>Germany</country>
        <OptionPrices/>
      </line>
    </CarPrices>
    <colors/>
    <Engine>
      <line>
        <fuel>diesel</fuel>
        <type>1.6</type>
      </line>
    </Engine>
    <Measurements>
  </Measurements>
  </line>
</Cars>
```

I tried different things but not with the correct behaviour/result. 
As requested I prefer to have a dynamic transformation. If we have a different input (for example bicycles, with the same-structure) this need also work.

note: for example Measurements is not in the input but we need it in the output.

Thanks for your help.

edit: only for xslt 1.0

Comment: The input has `CarPrices` as a child of `Transport`, the template `CarPrices` as a child of `Cars/line`, is the XSLT supposed to infer that "move" operation from the template and the source? As the input has several `line` elements, how is the XSLT supposed to map the `line` element(s) from the template to the input `line` element(s)?

Comment: Yes, the "move" is needed. I did tried with a for-each within a for-each, but for the OptionPrices this didn't work properly.

Comment: the line element always exist when the parent exist, if needed they can be edit to the template. If it's easier to achieve this without the template, it's also okay for me.  If the line elements has no childs only the parent exist.  I did have almost a solution with the for-each but for the element OptionPrice this was not an option.